# Android device can't connect to local web server on docker

Tags: android, docker, express, react-native

I'm running ExpressJS on localhost port 49160 (http://192.168.178.69:49160) on docker running on a MacBook pro.
On ios (simulator) the api works fine, however on android I can't seem to connect to my API.  On my android device I can open the above IP just fine in the browser. So I think it's an ADB or a docker problem. The mobile app is React-Native.

What I've tried:

- `adb reverse tcp:49160 tcp:49160`
- 127.0.0.1:49160
- 0.0.0.0:49160
- localhost:49160

Comment: Have you tried using the IP address and port of the docker machine (_192.168.178.69:49160_) to make a request from Android? For example: `fetch(http://192.168.178.69:49160/my-api-endpoint)`

Comment: @Kapobajza yes, that works from the browser but not from the app.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out http calls were blocked.
Fixed it by putting usesCleartextTraffic to true in the androidManifest file

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

I believe `true` is default, so I think you could also remove this line altogether